# Как создать двухмерный штрихкод в виде векторного изображения?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Я создаю двухмерные штрихкоды с помощью API-интерфейса iText, но они попадают в PDF-документ как растровые изображения, а во время печати на принтерах с низким разрешением качество штрихкода снижается. В результате не удается сканировать эти штрихкоды. Вот наш код:

```
BarcodePDF417 pdf417 = new BarcodePDF417();
String text = "BarcodePDF417 barcode";
pdf417.setText(text);
Image img = pdf417.getImage();        
document.add(img);
```

Мы берем метод placeBarcode() для создания векторного изображения. Мы попытались использовать его следующим образом:

```
Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(w * 72, h * 72);
Document doc = new Document(pageSize, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, getOutputStream());
doc.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
BarcodePDF417 pf = new BarcodePDF417();
pf.setText("BarcodePDF417 barcode");
Rectangle rc = pf.getBarcodeSize();
pf.placeBarcode(cb, BaseColor.BLACK, rc.getHeight(), rc.getWidth());
doc.close();
```

В результате страница становится полностью черной

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример BarcodePlacement. Здесь мы создаем три штрихкода PDF417:

```js
Image img = createBarcode(1, 1, pdfDoc);
doc.add(new Paragraph(String.format("This barcode measures %s by %s user units",
    img.getImageScaledWidth(), img.getImageScaledHeight())));
doc.add(img);
img = createBarcode(3, 3, pdfDoc);
doc.add(new Paragraph(String.format("This barcode measures %s by %s user units",
    img.getImageScaledWidth(), img.getImageScaledHeight())));
doc.add(img);
img = createBarcode(3, 1, pdfDoc);
doc.add(new Paragraph(String.format("This barcode measures %s by %s user units",
    img.getImageScaledWidth(), img.getImageScaledHeight())));
doc.add(img);
```

Результат выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Штрихкоды

Так выглядит один из штрихкодов внутри:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Векторные данные

Я добавляю вид изнутри, чтобы показать, что двухмерный штрихкод не добавляется как растровое изображение (как в вашем примере). Это векторное изображение, состоящее из группы маленьких прямоугольников. Вы можете проверить это самостоятельно в файле barcode_placement.pdf.
Объект Image не должен вас запутать. Если вы посмотрите на метод createBarcode(), то увидите, что Image в действительности является векторным изображением:

```js
public Image createBarcode(float mw, float mh, PdfDocument pdfDoc) {
    BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
    barcode.setCode("BarcodePDF417 barcode");
    return new Image(barcode.createFormXObject(Color.BLACK, pdfDoc)).scale(mw, mh);
}
```

Высота и ширина, которые передаются через метод scale(), определяют высоту и ширину маленьких прямоугольников. Во внутренней части штрихкода, можно увидеть следующее:

```js
0 21 3 1 re
```

Это прямоугольник, у которого x = 0, y = 21, ширина — 3, а высота —1.
Когда вы запрашиваете размер штрихкода, то получаете число необходимых прямоугольников. Размеры штрихкода будут рассчитываться следующим образом:

```js
Rectangle size = barcode.getBarcodeSize();
float width = mw * size.getWidth();
float height = mh * size.getHeight();
```

Вы допускаете, что значение size (размер в единицах пользователя) верно, только если mw и mh равняются 1.
Я использую значения для создания примера PdfFormXObject и переношу его в Image. Затем я могу добавить Image к документу, как и любое другое изображение. Основное отличие этого изображения от обычных заключается в том, что оно векторное.